# Subtracting strings

Tags: java, string, joptionpane, subtraction

I was asked to create a `JOptionPane` program which takes as many numbers as the user wants (as a string) and sums them together.
I thought about a pseudo like this:

1. make `int Total = 0`
2. receive input as string X
3. loop: `for (int i = 0; i<=X.length();i++)`

   1. create another string `S1` which takes the number from the beginning until the first space
   2. convert `S1` into a number and add it to Total
   3. subtract `S1` from `X`, and start the loop over
4. show total

So, my problem is at subtracting the `S1` from the `X`.

My code so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
int total = 0;
    String x = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("enter nums please");
    for (int i = 0; i<=x.length();i++){
        String s1 = x.substring (0, x.indexOf(' '));
        total += Integer.parseInt(s1);  
        x = x - s1;
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "the sum is" + total); }
```

Comment: Why don't you split the String `x` by whitespace ? Then parse the Strings in the resulting array and sum them up.

Comment: No arrays, didn't learn them. Maybe there's a completely another way to do it?

Comment: You could change the index starting index of the substring, increase the starting index by the length of the previous number etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is another interpretation of the method @ZouZou used, but doesn't actually break up your string, it remembers where its already looked, and works its way along the string

```
int total = 0;
String inputString = "12 7 8 9 52";
int prevIndex = 0;
int index = 0;
while (index > -1) {
  index = inputString.indexOf(' ', prevIndex);
  if (index > -1) {
    total += Integer.parseInt(inputString.substring(prevIndex, index));
    prevIndex = index + 1;
  } else {
    total += Integer.parseInt(inputString.substring(inputString.lastIndexOf(' ')+1));
break;
  }
}
System.out.println(total);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you didn't learn arrays yet, you can implement this like that :

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        int total = 0;
        String x = "12 7";
        String s1 = x.trim(); //trim the string
        while(!s1.isEmpty()){ //loop until s1 is not empty
            int index = x.indexOf(' ');//search the index for a whitespace
            if(index != -1){ //we found a whitespace in the String !
                s1 = s1.substring(0, index); //substract the right number
                total += Integer.parseInt(s1); 
                x = x.substring(index+1).trim(); //update the String x by erasing the number we just added to total
                s1 = x; //update s1
            } else {
                total += Integer.parseInt(s1); //when there is only one integer left in the String
                break; //break the loop this is over
            }
        }
        System.out.println(total);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution

```
int total = 0;
String x = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("enter nums please");

for (String s : x.split("\\s+")){
    total += Integer.parseInt(s);
}

System.out.println(total);
```

**Edit: *"can't use arrays"***- then use a `Scanner` to scan the `String` for `nextInt()`

```
int total = 0;
String x = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("enter nums please");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(x);  // use scanner to scan the line for nextInt()

while (scanner.hasNext()){
    total += scanner.nextInt();
}
System.out.println(total);
```

Comment: Well I know that, that's why I'm asking for help

Comment: See my edit. My original answer _kinda_ used an array, but my edited solution does not.